# GXT editing grid validation

Tags: validation, gwt, gxt, editing

I have recently started using GXT 3.0.1 and I'm trying to edit a grid where values entered into each column can affect other columns and data must be validated. I have tried both GridInlineEditing and GridRowEditing, but each are causing issues.

I need to calculate values based on the value of a cell. So let's say I update cell A, then cell B should update to reflect this value. Similarly for editing cell B, then cell A should update.  As well as this, I need to validate my changes before submitting.

GridInlineEditing - CompleteEditEvent fires each time tab is pressed and I can work out which values have changed based on storing previous value and lookng at Store.Record.getChange, so this works. However, validation simply doesn't work in 3.0.1 (see: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?255907-Validation-in-GridInlineEditing) and I cannot upgrade, so I hit a dead end here.

GridRowEditing - CompleteEditEvent only fires once entire row has been updated, so now validation is works, however, I cannot calculate column B after column A updated due to the event firing once.

Has anyone faced this same issue and found a solution?

Many thanks in adavnce.

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have recently started using GXT 3.0.1

GXT 3.0.1 was released over a year and a half ago, and two weeks ago 3.1.0 went out - try moving to GXT 3.1.0. In addition to many bug fixes, both row and inline editing now support field validation. If you cannot upgrade to 3.1.0, these changes were added in 3.0.5 or 6, see if you can upgrade at least that far. Knowing *why* you can't upgrade to either version will make it easier to make other suggestions - if you are relying on behavior that was fixed as part of another bug, it might make it contradictory for you to want bugfixes, but not all bug fixes.

If all else fails, perhaps look into extending the grid editing that you are using, consider overriding `completeEditing` or `doCompleteEditing` to modify the behavior directly, either by copying code from the newer releases, or by emulating the validation behavior through your own tooltip or alert, and not finishing the 'complete' code.

Comment: Thanks Colin. I've managed to ahieve a workaround by modifying my CompleteEditEvent event handler code and check to see if a change is not null, but the change.getValue() is null then pop up a dialog to say - value not valid. Upgrading is unfortunately, not an option.